# Way to Attach to an Oxyplot render exception

Tags: oxyplot

I have an oxyplot plot that is occasionally throwing an exception and displaying it to my users, but it does not bubble up to my application.  Is there a way to attach to an event that occurs when this exception is thrown?  Or some other way to bubble the exception up so I can see what it is and deal with it appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I just saw it is something done in the OxyPlot code (https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/4fa38033e722ade8d762b324afa54a078ab30917/Source/OxyPlot/PlotModel/PlotModel.Rendering.cs) line 131, function header on line 41.

I guess there could be different ways to solve it:
1.- Change the code to make it not be shown and compile the library again.
2.- Add the source code to your project, override the function, change the code to something that fit your needs.